# Left fluid div, center stretch up to max-width div, right fluid div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following situation:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="center"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

I need, that three dives (left,center,right) be in one row. Left and right div must take all empty space which is left after center div (left 50% of empty space, right 50% of empty space). Center div must stretch to maximum but it must have max-width:1000px. So, for example if width of the screen is <1000 center div must take all space.  So, center div possible widths are from 0 to 1000px. How to do it without js?

Comment: @Paulie_D They must be 0. Because empty space=0.

Comment: @Paulie_D No, they will not have content. They will have only borders.

Comment: @Paulie_D The key idea here that center div must stretch to maximum but to 1000px. So I can't set its width in something fixed.

Comment: @JimJim2000 solved it... check out my answer below.. you must be using a `flexbox` with `flex-basis` for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `flexbox` with the `center` div able to `shrink` only from the `flex-basis` of 1000px.

This ensures that the `center` will stretch to a maximum of 1000px

snippet below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container > div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left,
.right {
  flex: 1;
}
.center{
  flex: 0 1 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You set flex-bases to 1000px. But it is unknown. I don't know the least value. I know only maximum.

Comment: not that I have set `flex-grow` as `0` too and `flex-basis` will work like max-width... check it out by resizing the window

Comment: This is correct, the center can't grow beyond 1000px but it can shrink below it.

Comment: Ok, I need some time to check it ~ 10 min.

Answer (score 1):

Set `display:flex` to parent div

```css
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
}

#main div {
    -webkit-flex: 1;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
    -ms-flex: 1;  /* IE 10 */
    flex: 1;
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">Left</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;max-width:1000px;">Center</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgreen;">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4cfwb21x/1/)**

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
}
.container div{
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}
.left, .right{
  flex:1;
}
.center{
  flex: 25;
  max-width: 1000px;
  background: green;
}
.left{
  background: red;
}
.right{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="left">left</div>
   <div class="center">center</div>
   <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But in your example center has the least width. I do say in my question, that center must stretch to maximum. So, if width of the screen is <1000 center must take all space.

Comment: **So, center div possible widths are from 0 to 1000px** What is this means?